# Have SSH access - how to find domain?

Tags: ssh, url

I've been giving SSH access to a server.  All is fine, I can log in and do my work...

But I was not given a domain, so how can I view said work in a browser?

My files are located in:

```
/home/username/public_html/index.html
```

Visting the IP in the web browser get's me to a empty page.

Visiting `IP/username/index.html` results in 'Not found.'

Comment: Did you try the IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we're just blindly guessing, I'm going to go with

```
http://ip.add.re.ss/~username/index.html
http://hostname/~username/index.html
```

that's pretty standard for user directory pages, but ultimately you're best off asking the system administrator since this kind of thing is *highly* configurable.  For all we know, your home directory could be exported via NFS to some other server entirely, where it's mapped to something like

```
http://somesite.com/OurUsersSites/u/s/username/public_html/index.html
```

Comment: Success!!!  Who would've thought, a tilde!  It would've been nice if the sysadmin had left that info :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `hostname -f` to find the server's fully qualified domain name?

To give you much more of an answer, we will need to know exactly what kind of work that you are doing. For example, if your work involved publishing a web page with Apache, then the VirtualHosts directives in the config files in `/etc/apache` or `/etc/apache2` are your best bet. There are many other answers for many other examples.

Comment: Yes and that gets to a sparse looking empty page.  Trying to follow the directory path from there results in 'The requested URL was not found on this server.' messages.